# Connect with a default admin user in Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am trying to remove the authentication page and allow the connected user to be admin by default. It may be possible to do but because I am new with Django, I cannot find a solution to it...

I tried to do something like that in a file called "default_auth.py":

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_superuser = True
    is_active = True
    is_staff = True
    id = 1
    pk = 1


User.has_module_perms = True
User.has_perm = True


class Middleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        request.user = User()
        return self.response(request)
```

Then I saw on google that I need to comment this line: `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'`
and replace it with: `'myProject.default_auth.Middleware'`. And add this line: `myProject.default_auth.User` in the INSTALLED_APPS which is causing me an error when running the server.

Does anyone faced the same requirements or have an idea to do it ?

Thank you for your help

---

**EDIT1**:
Error is **django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.** and the exact django version I am using is: 2.0.13

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Git\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Git\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Git\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Git\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Git\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Git\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Git\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\wwakim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Git\myProject\pace_db\default_auth.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
  File "C:\Git\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Git\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Git\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 100, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Git\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Git\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myProject.default_auth.User'
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myProject.apps.PaceDbConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    # 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'myProject.default_auth.Middleware'
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: what is your version of the `django` and what is the error message? please provide it in the question.

Comment: Initial message edited

Comment: is `myProject` the name of your app inside your project?
i think you should to create the application for example `./manage.py startapp testmidlware` and move the `default_auth.py` inside it and after it change string in the `settings` to the `testmidlware.default_auth.Middleware`

Comment: Yes myProject is now at the same level of testmidlware. I tried to move the file as you were advising to do. Unfortunately, I am getting the same Apps aren't loaded yet error. There is something I don't understand... Do I need to add this default_auth in the INSTALLED_APPS of the settings ? As I have in my edit2 ? I tried to remove it and the error is: "Model class testmidlware.default_auth.User doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS."

Comment: In other words, is the MiddleWare section in settings associated somehow to the installed apps by django?

Comment: Please show the *full* `default_auth.py` in your question. The traceback shows that the error is coming from the import `from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser`, but you haven't shown that import or how it is used. Having `myProject.default_auth.User` in `INSTALLED_APPS` looks wrong - `User` is a class, not a Django app.

Comment: I have indeed removed this line in INSTALLED_APPS. I have edited the initial question with the entire content of default_auth.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I know it is not what I was asking for... But I manage to override the authentication default behaviour so it connect as an admin, no matter what is the provided password.

```
# File name : auth.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class LoginAsUserBackend:
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(username="AnAdminUsername")
        except:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except:
            return None
```

No need to change INSTALLED_APPS and MIDDLEWARE in settings but you will need to add:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'myProject.auth.LoginAsUserBackend' # Add this line
    )
```

I still have no idea of how to disable the authentication and connect directly as an admin when reaching the homepage...